# How to check if linux user has .sh file?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have to write script in bash that will check if logged users have any .sh files.
Checking who is logged in is simple just using:

```
w| awk '{print $1}'
```

But i have no idea how to check if they havy any .sh files

Comment: You mean like `find /home/user -name "*.sh"`?

Comment: [UsingFind](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) might be a place to start. Come back when you've tried something and encountered a specific problem in the course of doing so.

Comment: ...mind, there's no reason to name shell scripts with `.sh` extensions, and [lots of good reasons not to](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/), so if your real goal is to detect if a user has scripts in their home directory, looking for files with `.sh` at the end of their names is not a good way to do that. Detecting scripts is better done by (1) looking for files with an execute bit set in the permissions, and (2) checking the shebang (the first line specifying an interpreter).

Comment: Okey, i will try using find, maybe it will help

Comment: I think I have  found the solution

Comment: Also note that it is perfectly normal for users to have script files in their home directory, with a couple of them actually being created there by default when the user is set up (.profile, .bashrc).

Comment: Outside `awk`, `$1` is the first argument to the script, it has nothing to do with the output of the `who` line.

Comment: oh, but its showing all sh files for my logged user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the output of the `who` command and use that in your `find` command.

Since the same user can be logged in multiple times, it's a good idea to remove duplicates before looping.

```
#!/bin/bash
who| awk '{print $1}' | sort -u | while read -r username; do
    find /home/"$username" -name "*.sh"
done
```

Comment: Thank you, but one question, what is "rest" doing?

Comment: I got rid of it in my last edit.

Comment: Before I added the `sort -u` I was reading the variable directly from `who` without using `awk`, so `rest` would get the rest of the line after the username.

Comment: okey, i have one problem, i tried to logg in by "su - user" and "who" isn't showing any other users except the main one

Comment: Only one user can be logged in on a particular terminal, and it's the original login. `su` doesn't override that.

Comment: But i've opened multiple terminals,  each for each user

Comment: When you open the terminal, it's associated with the user who opened the terminal. Running `su` in the terminal doesn't change that.